# C# WPF ConnectionString Class Security

Tags: c#, wpf, security, encryption

I'm just building my application, but wish to test it online, rather than locally to see how it performs.

Essentially, as it will be a distributed application, I want it to be secure. I want the connection string to be encrypted so later, when I perform obfuscation, it will increase overall security of the application.

http://puu.sh/is8IX/12ccc76d65.png

Overall, how does it look? As it works perfectly locally, I just wish to improve it overall as I'm heading in to an SE job and wish to be prepared.

Apart from security, any other advice?

Comment: if you can, remove SQL completely from your client app. Build a small SSL protected WCF service and communicate with it using encrypted parameters and let it do the work.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction? It's been about 2 years since I've messed with ASP.NET and ADO 

http://puu.sh/isdVV/fe9e53245f.png

How to I get the C# WPF Application to communicate through SSL with the Entities model? I can set the rights, but I'm not sure of cross functionality. I was never taught it.

Comment: ASP.NET has nothing to do with WCF Services. a WCF service is like a DLL on the web. Search on google there are tons of tutorials

Comment: Franck, wondering if you can aid in answering this for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898004/wcf-data-service-exposing-issues Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Personally regardless of obfuscation or not, I would not keep the connection string information in the class, sorry had to say this even though you mentioned not security related.

Apart from that,

I would change your code to use using statements, example:

```
using(var connection = U_SQLConnection.GetConnection())
{
   using(var command = new SqlCommand(""))
   {
     using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
     {
     }
   }
}
```

You don't "Have To" use using statements, but mostly they would be considered good practice. Also from a personal point of view, I would not keep the SqlConnection variable globally in the class either (SqlConnection _con). If you take a look you are in fact setting it twice, once in line 4 and again on line 32 (line numbers are more guessing), it might not break anything, but seems like it is not required.

Comment: Appreciate it :) Seems like your code is much simpler to read also.

Any ideas for encryption? Where would I put it apart from the class? In to the config file?

Comment: Pleasure, glad you found it useful.