# WCF Data Service Exposing Issues

Tags: wcf, service

I've another issue, that I just can't get my head around. I can't see what I'm doing wrong! I've resorted to going back through tutorials, but to no avail.

http://puu.sh/isqE9/e87e6a55af.png

For some reason, even after deleting the project and reloading it numerous times, I cannot expose the data in the web service. I can successfully query the database that the entity model is imitating but I cannot expose it locally through my web browser. For some reason I cannot find the file, even though I've checked many times that the file path, port number etc are all correct.

Any ideas? Driving me insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is located here: [WCF Data Service 5.6 quick start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255201/wcf-data-service-5-6-quick-start)

Turns out entity framework 6 is a little different when using entity framework 5 which should work straight off the bat.